# Is there a way to hook the system call table with a loadable module of a system with an ARM based processor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, hook, linux-device-driver, system-calls

Trying to create a device driver to hook the system call table on my raspberry pi 3b+. I've written one that works well for X86, but on the raspberry pi I'm stumped on how to disable write protections on the sys_call_table so I can put in the address for my function.

On X86, to disable write protection you would insert something like

`write_cr0 (read_cr0 () & (~ 0x10000));`

to your code.

Does anyone have any idea on how to approach disabling write protection with an ARM based processor (via the loadable module code of course)?

Comment: Does set_memory_rw help?

Comment: @Jose No, I believe it doesn't work for sys_call_table (at least for ARM, I think someone got it working in x86)